# Android Widget Button only fires once

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

My widget consists of a few textviews and a button.
The button press calls a webservice that populates the textviews.

This works fine, however the button only does this once then does nothing after the first press. There is no error in the logcat.

I have removed the webservice methods to make it simpler to read. The code below still displays the same problem: The button press only fires once.

Anyone able to help please?

EDIT: I think the issue could be that I don't have a broadcast receiver?

```
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class DashboardWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    static String response = "";
    static clsDashboardResponse result;
    static Context cont;
    static AppWidgetManager appWidgMan;
    static int appWidgID = 0;
    static String count = "";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds[i]);
        }
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.dashboard_widget);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button, buildButtonPendingIntent(context));
    }

    public static PendingIntent buildButtonPendingIntent(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    }

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int appWidgetId) {

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.dashboard_widget);
        cont = context;
        appWidgMan = appWidgetManager;
        appWidgID = appWidgetId;
        count = count + "a";
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.txvWidgetSales, count);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy 'at' h:mm:ss a");
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.txvWidgetDate, format.format(cal.getTime()));

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}
```

Comment: show where u set the button onclick listener

Comment: Try to replace this code : PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,(int) (Math.random() * 100), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Comment: @ Haresh Chhelana I replaced PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); with the code above but it made no difference.

Comment: @Panther remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button, buildButtonPendingIntent(context)); sets the event handler